# Hiding add to cart for a particular category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I have tried many code examples and none of them have worked.

My site has 2 main categories (New & Used) each have about 10 sub cats with them. I am using the YITH request a quote plugin but I only want to use it on the Used items, Is there a way I can display the Add To Cart button for just the New category?

the url is set up like site.com/used-equipment/sub-category/product-name/

Here is the code I have tried.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_add_to_cart_buttons', 1 );

    function remove_add_to_cart_buttons() {
      if( is_product_category( array( 'used-equipment' )) { 
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**— Updated —**

You need to use [**`has_term()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) conditional function to make it work. **`has_term()`** accept category or subcategory names, slugs or Ids, (a single string or an array of values).

Here is your changed code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_add_to_cart_buttons', 1 );

function remove_add_to_cart_buttons() {

    if( has_term( 'used-equipment', 'product_cat')) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    }
}
```

This code is tested and works. It removes on the shop pages and on archives pages the add-to-cart button on products that belongs to a defined category or subcategory…

*This goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Comment: When adding that, I get an error of "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' "

Comment: @WebbieWorks sorry I have forget to put my real tested code… I do it now…